# Как исправить повышение heap used у v8?

Tags: node.js

Есть сервер на nodejs (Express 4)

Это обычный сервер в котором есть пара роутеров 
/api
/api/documents

и подприложение express admin (закоментированно было на вермя теста)

Вот код сервера

```
// Required
// =============================================================================
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        express    = require('express'),
        app        = express(),
        api       = require('./routes/api/routers.js'),
        admin      = require('./admin.js'),

        config     = require('./config/index.js'),
        log        = require('./libs/log.js')(module),
        ENV        = process.argv[2]||'development';


// Settings
// =============================================================================
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"public/dist/"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('port',config.get(ENV+':server:port'));
app.set('host',config.get(ENV+':server:host'));

// metrica for detected memory lead
require('look').start(config.get(ENV+':look:port'));


// Routers
// =============================================================================
app.use('/api',api);
// app.use('/',admin);

// Middlewares
// =============================================================================
app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
    log.error(err);

    if(req.xhr){
        res.status(500).send({ error: err });
        return;
    }
    //error page 5xx
    res.status(500).send('Server error!');

});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);

    //error page 404
    res.send('Page of this URL <em>'+req.url+'</em> is not found');
});


if(!module.parent){
    app.listen(app.get('port'),app.get('host'),function(){
        log.info('Server start on host '+app.get('host')+', on port '+app.get('port')+'.');
    });
}else{
    module.exports = app;
}
```

Файл с роутерами под api

```
var express = require('express'),
        router  = express.Router();

//example
router.route('/')
        .get(function(req,res,next){
            res.send('Api!');
        })
        .post()
        .put()
        .delete();

router.route('/documents')
    .get(function(req,res,next){
        res.send('Documents');
    })
    .post()
    .put()
    .delete();

module.exports=router;
```

В тесте модуля look в графике v8 heap used постоянно мало по малу растёт память. Это связано с роутерами? Как это исправить?
[image: Результаты метрики]

Comment: До каких пределов оно растет?

Comment: DmitriySimushev, ну за 2 мин на 1 МВ растёт, раньше вообще непоколебимо было (когда был чисто сервер с одним роутером)

Comment: за 1 час ровно на 10 МВ ростёт и продолжает, я не знаю в чём проблема(

Comment: За 2 минуты на 1 мб, а за 60 минут на 10 мб. :) Не раз слышал про утечки памяти  node.js. Могу только предложить ребут по крону и посочувствовать.

Comment: Nick Volynkin, я просто видел статистики как должно быть, и мой график похож на утечку( Самое главное в том, что я просто запускаю сервак и делаю один запрос на url /api, всё)) и при этом идёт утечка, почему?как? что не так? незнаю..

Comment: за время использования ноды заметил за ней интересную особенность, пока есть свободная память в системе, она будет пытаться ее подмять под себя. Чем больше происходит аллокаций, тем быстрее она будет подминать под себя системную память. понаблюдайте за heap used дольше, вот когда начнет отрабатывать gc, можно будет сравнить, есть ли утечки. для ускорения данного процесса можно аллоцировать большие объекты с последующим удалением их.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Говорить об утечки памяти в данном контексте преждевременно.
На самом деле внутри модулей (например тот-же самый express) на каждый запрос создаются функции, объекты - это память. 10Мб - это ничто для v8. Все старые объекты хранятся в памяти, размер которой ограничивается max-old-space-size директивой. На 64 битных системах v8 по умолчанию потребляет не более 1Gb. Эпизодически запускается GC который находит и вычищает неиспользуемый мусор.
Запустите ноду с --expose-gc посмотрите когда срабатывает GC и как при этом изменяется размер heap. Также можете понизить max-old-space-size и посмотреть в долгой перспективе, как будет потребляться память.